# Filter a dictionary based on the value of its date keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, date, filter

I want to import articles from as many sources around the world as from a certain date.

```
import requests
url = ('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?'
       'country=us&'
       'apiKey=de9e19b7547e44c4983ad761c104278f')
response = requests.get(url)

response_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(response.json())

articles = {article for article in response_dataframe['articles'] if article['publishedAt'] >= '2019-01-04T11:30:00Z'}
print(articles)
```

But I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-0f21f2f50907> in <module>
      2 response_dataframe['articles'][1]['publishedAt']
      3 
----> 4 articles = {article for article in response_dataframe['articles'] if article['publishedAt'] >= '2018-01-04T11:30:00Z'}
      5 print(articles)

<ipython-input-84-0f21f2f50907> in <setcomp>(.0)
      2 response_dataframe['articles'][1]['publishedAt']
      3 
----> 4 articles = {article for article in response_dataframe['articles'] if article['publishedAt'] >= '2018-01-04T11:30:00Z'}
      5 print(articles)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Therefore how to select a range of articles according by selecting on these keys ?
The expected output is a dataframe sorting the articles by the day and the newspaper.

```
              The New York Times                                The Washington Post                                The Financial Times  
2007-01-01    . What Sticks from '06. Somalia Orders Islamis... New Ebola Vaccine Gives 100 Percent Protecti...
2007-01-02    . Heart Health: Vitamin Does Not Prevent Death... Flurry of Settlements Over Toxic Mortgages M...
2007-01-03    . Google Answer to Filling Jobs Is an Algorith... Jason Miller Backs Out of White House Commun...
2007-01-04    . Helping Make the Shift From Combat to Commer... Wielding Claims of ‘Fake News,’ Conservative...
2007-01-05    . Rise in Ethanol Raises Concerns About Corn a... When One Party Has the Governor’s Mansion an
...
```

My Python version is 3.6.6

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Why are you putting the JSON response in a dataframe? Why is a set comprehension used, are you trying to avoid duplicates of some kind?

Comment: Put differently, can you clearly illustrate what your expected outcome is here?

Comment: The code executes without any errors for me. When I `print (response)`, I get `<Response [200]>`. I am not sure if that's the expected response, but I can't reproduce the error. @MartijnPieters: What version are you using?

Comment: same here, code executes perfectly on python 3.6.4

Comment: Ah, I see. The code **posted** produces an empty set (no articles with that publication date). The traceback doesn't use the same criteria however, it uses `>=` to filter with, producing a non-empty match, and then you try to put those dictionaries in a set. I was using the line from the traceback.

Comment: At any rate, `[a for a in response.json()['articles'] if a['publishedAt'] >= '2018-01-04T11:30:00Z']` works and produces a list with 20 dictionaries, all with unique titles and urls, so I don't know why a set would be required here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for your help. I put it in a dataframe because I didn't knew how to filter the json. I used a set comprehension because I wasn't sure if I should have put an array. The output I expect is a dataframe or at least an array with the titles of the articles of the newspaper sorted by day and by newspaper.

Comment: And how should multiple titles for a given source on a given day be handled? Your expected output can't handle two or more New York Times articles on 2007-01-05.

Comment: Side note: did you mean to publish a live, valid API key? If not, reset the key *ASAP*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, the API key is not mine, I found it in the [docs](https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints/top-headlines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are filtering dictionaries then trying to put them in a set. Your expected outcome does not require you to de-duplicate anything, so the easiest path away from the error is to use a list comprehension instead; just swap out `{...}` curly braces for square braces:

```
articles = [article for article in response_dataframe['articles'] if article['publishedAt'] >= '2019-01-04T11:30:00Z']
```

However, if you are going to put the data into a dataframe for processing, you would be much better of with using the [`pandas.io.json.json_normalize()` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html); it can produce a dataframe for you from list-and-dictionaries structure typically loaded from a JSON source.

Start with loading just the article data you want into a dataframe and you can filter and re-arrange from there; the following code loads all data into a single dataframe with a new `date` column, derived from the `publishAt` information:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df = json_normalize(response.json(), 'articles')

# make the datetime column a native type, and add a date-only column
df['publishedAt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['publishedAt'])
df['date'] = df['publishedAt'].dt.date

# move source dictionary into separate columns rather than dictionaries
source_columns = df['source'].apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('source_')
df = pd.concat([df.drop(['source'], axis=1), source_columns], axis=1)
```

That gives you a dataframe with all the article information, as a complete dataframe with native types, with the columns `author`, `content`, `description`, `publishedAt`, `date`, `title`, `url`, `urlToImage` and the `source_id` and `source_name` columns from the `source` mapping.

I note that the *API* allows you to filter by date already, I'd rely on that instead of filtering locally, as you can save time and bandwidth by having the API give you a smaller dataset. The API also lets you apply sorting, again a good idea.

To group the rows by date and source name, you would have to [pivot the dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html); the dates should be the index, the columns the name of the source, and the titles as the values:

```
df.pivot(index='date', columns='source_name', values='title')
```

This fails however, because this format does not have space for more than one title per source per day:

```
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

In the JSON data served to me, there are multiple CNN and Fox News articles just for today.

You *could* aggregate multiple titles into lists:

```
pd.pivot_table(df,
    index='date', columns='source_name', values='title',
    aggfunc=list)
```

For the default 20 results for 'today' this gives me:

```
>>> pd.pivot_table(
...     df, index='date', columns='source_name', values='title',
...     aggfunc=list
... )
source_name                                            Bbc.com                        ...                                                                Youtube.com
date                                                                                  ...
2019-01-05   [Paul Whelan: Russia rules out prisoner swap f...                        ...                          [Bears Buzz: Eagles at Bears - Wildcard Round ...

[1 rows x 18 columns]
```

Personally, I'd just keep the dataframe limited to dates, titles and source names, with a date index:

```
>>> df[['date', 'source_name', 'title']].set_index('date').sort_values(['date', 'source_name'])
                    source_name                                              title
date
2019-01-05              Bbc.com  Paul Whelan: Russia rules out prisoner swap fo...
2019-01-05            Bloomberg  Russia Says FBI Arrested Russian Citizen on Pa...
2019-01-05                  CNN  Pay raises frozen for Pence, Cabinet members u...
2019-01-05                  CNN  16 big questions on Robert Mueller's Russia in...
2019-01-05            Colts.com  news What They're Saying: Colts/Texans, Wild C...
2019-01-05             Engadget  Pandora iOS update adds offline playback for A...
2019-01-05             Espn.com  Roger Federer wins Hopman Cup with Switzerland...
2019-01-05             Fox News  Japanese 'Tuna King' pays record $3M for prize...
2019-01-05             Fox News  Knicks' Turkish star Enes Kanter to skip Londo...
2019-01-05          Latimes.com  Flu toll mounts in California, with 42 deaths ...
2019-01-05             NBC News  After the fire: Blazes pose hidden threat to t...
2019-01-05           Newser.com  After Backlash, Ellen Not Ditching Support for...
2019-01-05              Npr.org  Three Dead After Fight Escalates Into Shooting...
2019-01-05              Reuters  French 'yellow vests' rail against unrepentant...
2019-01-05             The Hill  Trump: 'I don’t care' that most federal employ...
2019-01-05  The Huffington Post  5 Children Dead After Church Van Crashes On Wa...
2019-01-05            The Verge  Apple seeks to end bent iPad Pro controversy w...
2019-01-05    Thisisinsider.com  Kanye West surprised Kim Kardashian with a $14...
2019-01-05            USA Today  See 'Mean Girls' co-stars Lindsay Lohan and Jo...
2019-01-05          Youtube.com  Bears Buzz: Eagles at Bears - Wildcard Round -...
```

The above is sorted by date and by source, so multilpe titles from the same source are grouped.

Comment: Many thanks ! And how to filter by date from the API to save time and bandwidth by having the API give you a smaller dataset ? Would I always get 20 results or may I get some more ?

Comment: @ThePassenger: you already found the documentation, it lists what parameters are acceptable. The [`top-headlines` path](https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints/top-headlines) accepts a `pageSize` parameter, for example. The [`everything` path](https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints/everything) lets you query for a range of dates.